# textFieldShouldReturn is not working anymore

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, textfield

On iPad, textFieldShouldReturn is not working anymore. I had it working until like five minutes ago, suddenly the method is not called anymore … Any Ideas? Below is the code, the only thing changed was a notification for an UITextView… Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)tf
{
NSString* newName = textField.text;
textLabel.text = textField.text;
NSLog(@"Called!");

newName = [newName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
NSString* newPath = [[currentFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newName]; 
NSLog(@"%@",newPath);
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:currentFilePath toPath:newPath error:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataSaved" object:nil];
[currentFilePath retain];
currentFilePath = newPath;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
[currentFilePath retain];
// Write out the contents of home directory to console

NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
textLabel.alpha = 1.0;
textField.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[tf resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: best possibility - you might have accidentally removed the delegate for the textfield.

Comment: Okay, you were right. Would be nice if you could add it as an answer so that I can accept it as answer ;) Thanks alot! Made my day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

best possibility - you might have accidentally removed the delegate for the textfield.

Answer (score 3):

Check for `(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` method in IOS 6. You have to set the `textField` delegate in XIB and write down the following code:

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```